# java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET AND EPIPE

Tags: android, sockets, nullpointerexception, socketexception

***EDIT***

If people dont' think this question is clear enough please just ask for some clarity instead of marking down as being honest I'm not sure how I should ask this question!!

I am trying to follow some c# code and convert into java to send data to a thermal printer.  I have created a method called processImageFiles, here I take image files in the form of byte arrays and process them as I wish, here is my method below:

```
public void processImageFiles(byte[] logoImage, int fileTypeId, int printOrder, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        switch (fileTypeId)
        {
            case 1:
                break;

            case 2:
                LOGOS t_icon1 = new LOGOS();
                LOGOS t_icon2 = new LOGOS();
                LOGOS t_icon3 = new LOGOS();
                LOGOS t_icon4 = new LOGOS();
                LOGOS t_icon5 = new LOGOS();
                LOGOS t_icon6 = new LOGOS();

                switch (printOrder)
                {
                    case 1:
                        t_icon1 = BitmapToByte(logoImage);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        t_icon2 = BitmapToByte(logoImage);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        t_icon3 = BitmapToByte(logoImage);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        t_icon4 = BitmapToByte(logoImage);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        t_icon5 = BitmapToByte(logoImage);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        t_icon6 = BitmapToByte(logoImage);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                sendLogo(t_icon1,t_icon2,t_icon3,t_icon4,t_icon5,t_icon6, context);          
        }
```

In this I call sendLogo:

2. sendLogo (below):

   ```
   public void sendLogo(LOGOS icon1, LOGOS icon2, LOGOS icon3, LOGOS icon4, LOGOS icon5, LOGOS  icon6, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   byte[] temp1 = new byte[3];
   byte[] temp2 = new byte[4];

   temp1[0] = 0x1c;
   temp1[1] = 0x71;
   temp1[2] = 6;

   sendToPrinter(temp1, context);
   sendLogoPart(icon1, context);
   sendLogoPart(icon2, context);
   sendLogoPart(icon3, context);
   sendLogoPart(icon4, context);
   sendLogoPart(icon5, context);
   sendLogoPart(icon6, context);
   closeSocket(printerSocket);
   }
   ```

then I call sendToPrinter:

```
public void sendToPrinter(final byte [] data, final Context context) throws IOException {

Thread thread = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            final String ipAddress = sharedPreferences.getString("IP", "null");
            final int portNo = 9100;
            if(printerSocket==null) {
                printerSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, portNo);
            }
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(printerSocket.getOutputStream());
            dOut.writeInt(data.length);
            dOut.write(data);
            dOut.flush();
            dOut.close();


            Log.i("data sent"," to printer");

            printedSuccessfully = true;

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Unknown Host Exception Error: ", String.valueOf(e));
            printedSuccessfully = false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("IO Exception Error: ", String.valueOf(e));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
thread.start();
}
```

and

sendLogoPart :

```
 public void sendLogoPart(final LOGOS icon, final Context context) throws IOException {
        final byte[] tmp = new byte[4];

        tmp[0] = (byte)(icon.y >> 3);  //4;
        tmp[1] = 0x0;

        tmp[2] = (byte)icon.x;  //32;
        tmp[3] = 0x0;
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }
```

Here is the logos class

```
public static class LOGOS{
    public int y;
    public int x;
    public byte[] logo;
}
```

I get a couple of issues when I run this, first of all when sendLogoPart is called the first time I get an error of a nullpointer in the sendToPrinter method at dOut.writeInt(data.length);

```
01-08 13:35:04.302    2598-2766/com.etlie.stockclient E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-252
    Process: com.etlie.stockclient, PID: 2598
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.etlie.stockclient.DBManager.Controller.Controller$26.run(Controller.java:1992)
```

Once this causes the app to crash, it the logcat continues to produce different error messages in relation to the socket:

```
01-08 13:35:04.562    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
01-08 13:35:04.562    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
01-08 13:35:04.562    2598-2772/com.etlie.stockclient W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=29: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41eddba8)
01-08 13:35:04.562    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:499)
01-08 13:35:04.562    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:468)
01-08 13:35:04.562    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
01-08 13:35:04.562    2598-2598/com.etlie.stockclient I/STOCK DOWNLOAD...﹕ PROCESSING
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(DataOutputStream.java:180)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at com.etlie.stockclient.DBManager.Controller.Controller$26.run(Controller.java:1992)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:156)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:499)
01-08 13:35:04.567    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:468)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(DataOutputStream.java:180)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at com.etlie.stockclient.DBManager.Controller.Controller$26.run(Controller.java:1992)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at  at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:156)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:466)
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2771/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ ... 5 more
01-08 13:35:04.572    2598-2770/com.etlie.stockclient W/System.err﹕ libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:466)
```

Line 1992 is the line that crashed the app in the firstplace.  If someone could help me on this I'd greatly appreciate it as I really don't know what the problem is, whether there is an issue with sendToPrinter being call to many times to quickly causing a problem with the socket

Comment: `EPIPE` most likely means you tried to write on a closed socket. Somehow your socket got closed without you detecting it, so writing on it provokes a `Broken Pipe` error. But I have no solution sorry.

Comment: @shkschneider thank you for your reply.  Could it be that from when the sendToPrinter is first called there maybe a crossover to when it is called the second time in sendLogoPart?